# Convert a matrix to a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, type-conversion

I'm working with numpy using a matrix that is 1x3. My question is:
Exists a way to convert that matrix into a tuple that contains the elements of the matrix in order? For example, if the matrix is

```
A=matrix([[1,2,3]])
```

get

```
B=(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Remember `(1,2,3)` is a tuple. A list would be `[1,2,3]`

Comment: But my problem is that the word 'matrix' exists and when you get something in the matrix, it still has the word 'matrix' at the start.

Comment: you can extract undelying array with `matrix([[1,2,3]]).A`, or flattened 1d underlying array with `matrix([[1,2,3]]).A1`, and work with them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do something as simple as this:

```
>>> A = matrix([[1,2,3]])
>>> B = A.tolist()
>>> B
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> B = A.tolist()[0]
>>> B
[1, 2, 3]
```

EDIT:

As Christian points out, I see that you have changed your desired output to a tuple. As Christian suggests, all you need to do is this:

```
>>> B = tuple(A.tolist()[0])
>>> B
(1, 2, 3)
```

`A` will still function as a matrix, but `B` is now a tuple and so will not function as a matrix.

Comment: Thanks!
If the matrix is of 3x1 still works?

Comment: Remember that to convert a list into a tuple just do: `B = tuple(list_here)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want get a list from 3x1, 1x3, use [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
>>> from numpy import matrix
>>> matrix([[1,2,3]]).flatten().tolist()[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> matrix([[1],[2],[3]]).flatten().tolist()[0]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Alternative using [`A1` attribute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html#numpy.matrix.A1):

```
>>> matrix([[1],[2],[3]]).A1.tolist()
[1, 2, 3]
>>> matrix([[1,2,3]]).A1.tolist()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: In first case adding `flatten()` doesn't do anything, you can just do `matrix([[1,2,3]]).tolist()[0]`.

Comment: @Akavall, added `flatten()` to make sure it work for both case.

Comment: I used, and results useful. Thanks!

Comment: I don't like this `[0]`, one option would be `np.matrix([[1],[2],[3]]).A1.tolist()`

Comment: @alko, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer with your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.matrix([[1,2,3]])
>>> m
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> B = tuple(m.A[0])
>>> B
(1, 2, 3)
```

Edit: Inspired by @falsetru's use of `flatten`, this is a more general solution:

```
>>> tuple(m.A.flatten())
(1, 2, 3)
```

I think using `flatten` on an `array` makes more sense because it converts 2D array into 1D, while this cannot be done for matrices.